# 4-4-5 accounting calendar in java

Tags: java, calendar, java-time, accounting, rfc2445

I have to use the 4-4-5 accounting calendar in java.

I'm finding a way to have, given a specific date the current month, the corresponding accounting month.

For example, for the year 2020 I will have this accounting months:

```
29-Dec  25-Jan
26-Jan  22-Feb
23-Feb  28-Mar
29-Mar  25-Apr
26-Apr  23-May
24-May  27-Jun
28-Jun  25-Jul
26-Jul  22-Aug
23-Aug  26-Sep
27-Sep  24-Oct
25-Oct  21-Nov
22-Nov  26-Dec
```

So, for example, given a date 28 Apr I need to receive something like this:

```
26-Apr  23-May
```

I tried to use also  [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html) project with AccountingChronology an AccountingChronologyBuilder. But, sincerely, I struggle to understand how to use it.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and also provide more details on the logic of the calendar? Why does it start on 29-Dec instead of 1-Jan? I assume it's because it's required to start on a certain day of the week, but you haven't specified which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough to get those dates using the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

Define your chronology. Instantiate a [`AccountingChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingChronology.html) by using [`AccountingChronologyBuilder`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingChronologyBuilder.html). Specify the attributes that fit your particular business practices. Notice how we specify 4-4-5 via the [`AccountingYearDivision`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingYearDivision.html).

```java
AccountingChronology acctChrono = new AccountingChronologyBuilder()
        .endsOn(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
        .inLastWeekOf(Month.DECEMBER)
        .withDivision(AccountingYearDivision.QUARTERS_OF_PATTERN_4_4_5_WEEKS)
        .leapWeekInMonth(12)
        .toChronology();
```

Use that chronology to instantiate [`AccountingDate`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingDate.html). Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to move from one date to another.

```
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    AccountingDate start = acctChrono.date(2020, month, 1);
    AccountingDate end = start.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(start.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) + "  "
                     + end.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

*Output*

```
2019-12-29  2020-01-25
2020-01-26  2020-02-22
2020-02-23  2020-03-28
2020-03-29  2020-04-25
2020-04-26  2020-05-23
2020-05-24  2020-06-27
2020-06-28  2020-07-25
2020-07-26  2020-08-22
2020-08-23  2020-09-26
2020-09-27  2020-10-24
2020-10-25  2020-11-21
2020-11-22  2020-12-26
```

Comment: I was looking at the API, and two things I don't understand. Why leapWeekInMonth 12, and why inLastWeekOf instead of nearestEndOf? Are those just standard accounting conventions? I had gotten as far as creating the chronology (and converting some dates) but I had `.leapWeekInMonth(2)`. Admittedly, this is my first time looking at this API.

Comment: I just picked a value for `leapWeekInMonth`. It's up to you to pick the value you need/want. --- Try changing `inLastWeekOf()` to `nearestEndOf()` and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was just curious if there was a reason you picked the value you did. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: @BasilBourque I had deliberately not made it a link, since a link is already provided in the question, but thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Andreas The Question linked to the Javadoc package page. I added link to the *ThreeTen-Extra* project page. I added more links to help guide the uninitiated. And thanks for your excellent Answer, very helpful.

Comment: @BasilBourque *FYI:* Using link references makes the answer source easier to read (and write). Use the link button when editing to automatically format/sort/merge link references.